# Regular expression, match a partial word, C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match instances that have duplicate partial words in a file, where the word needs to match up until one instance has an underscore _Id, and the other instance is a partial match on the word.

something along the lines of:

The regex i'm using is:   `/^(\S+) (?=(?s:.)*\1.*).*`

```
public Guid? Something_Id { get; set;}
public Guid? SomethingId {get; set;}

public Guid? AnotherProp_Id { get; set;}
public Guid? AnotherPropId { get; set; }
```

Where this should return 2 matching instances.

Almost make more sense to include a remove for all underscores, and then match for duplicates on a forward/backward lookup ?

Bit stuck on how to do that

Comment: Could you give a sample of what it should do? You explanation is a bit hard to follow. What is an instance? How do you define a partial match?

Comment: RegEx's generally work on a line-by-line process unless you specify no-newlines (which it doesn't look like you have) and then you'll need to look explicitly for the newlines otherwise you'll get matches on 'public' etc

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse C#. Have you considered using a C# parser like Roslyn?

Comment: Yeah, this is essentially something I was trying to use to scan multiple cs files inside visual studio on it's Find feature, since it allows regexp. I am trying to hunt down duplicate fields essentially in the same file, where 2 versions of the same field exist in the file, but the duplicated & incorrect field does not contain an _Id. But perhaps this isn't the best way to go about this.   The goal was to have it show me matches on SomethingId, and AnotherPropId, as these are duplicated fields that were never removed, and were replaced by the aforementioned _Id fieldnaming prop.

Comment: I meant by partial matching of the words is by matching Something_Id and SomethingId together.  If the underscore was removed, these are the same property.  But they could be anywhere in the file, lines several lines above, or below each other.

Comment: I think for what I'm trying to do this is a poor direction. I'll try the Roslyn route

Comment: Yes - your problem is clear - but looks like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).   ie you're asking how to do it in regex when regex doesn't appear to be the correct tool for this.    You could use [stylecop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (has a VS plugin) to find variables with the wrong naming convention or Resharper (R#) has a similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Forword

Whilst it has been [correctly highlighted via a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922883/regular-expression-match-a-partial-word-c-sharp#comment55609090_33922883) that a RegEx might not be the best solution - this answer offers a RegEx solution the question asked for.

### Regular Expression

```
(?:
  ^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)_Id\b[^\r\n]+.*?
  ^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\1)Id\b
|
  ^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)Id\b[^\r\n]+.*?
  ^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\2)_Id\b
)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iC9qK5/1

### Visualisation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Notes

It looks repeated because it can match in any order, either `*Id` then `*_Id` or `*_Id` then `*Id`.

This also allows anything to be on the lines between.

### Code

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(
        @"(?:
          ^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)_Id\b[^\r\n]+.*?
          ^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\1)Id\b
        |
          ^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)Id\b[^\r\n]+.*?
          ^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\2)_Id\b
        )", 
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

### Part 2: Remove the offenders

If this does the job for you - you could perform a replacement with a slightly modified version

#### Regular Expression

```
(?:
  (^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)_Id\b[^\r\n]+(.*?))
  (^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\2)Id\b)[^\r\n]+\r?\n
|
  (\r?\n^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)Id\b[^\r\n]+)(.*?)
  (^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\6)_Id\b)[^\r\n]+
)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iC9qK5/2

#### Replacement

```
$1$7$8
```

#### Visualisation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Code

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
        @"(?:
          (^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)_Id\b[^\r\n]+(.*?))
          (^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\2)Id\b)[^\r\n]+\r?\n
        |
          (\r?\n^[^\r\n]+?\b(\S+)Id\b[^\r\n]+)(.*?)
          (^[^\r\n]+?\b(?:\6)_Id\b)[^\r\n]+
        )", 
        "$1$7$8", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```